# Getting rank (row number) for every year

Tags: sql, rank, partition

I have a database with emissions and populations. I'm using the following query to get emissions per capita and a rank for each country:

```sql
SELECT 
      cp.year as year, 
      emissions, 
      ci.id as countryid, 
      country_name, 
      country_iso_code, 
      emissions / population as per_capita, 
      CASE WHEN emissions / population IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE RANK() OVER (ORDER 
      BY CASE WHEN emissions / population IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, emissions / 
      population DESC) END AS rank 
FROM country_emissions ce 
      RIGHT JOIN 
                 country_info ci ON (ci.countryid = ce.countryid) 
      RIGHT JOIN 
                 country_population cp ON (ce.countryid = cp.countryid) AND (cp.year = ce.year) 
WHERE 
      cp.year = 2010 
GROUP BY 
      ce.countryid, ce.year, ce.emissions, ci.id, ci.countryid, ci.country_iso_code, ci.country_name, cp.id, cp.countryid, cp.year, cp.population 
ORDER BY 
    emissions / population;
```

And it will give me the following results:

```
 year |  emissions  | countryid |          country_name          | country_iso_code |         per_capita         | rank
------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+------
 2010 |     212.686 |        14 | Burundi                        | BDI              | 0.000024260031732887110996 |  201
 2010 |    2020.517 |        40 | Congo, Dem. Rep.               | COD              | 0.000031314550846568314439 |  200
 2010 |     517.047 |       187 | Chad                           | TCD              | 0.000043496106148444352170 |  199
 2010 |     612.389 |       174 | Somalia                        | SOM              | 0.000050807074589095381376 |  198
 2010 |     590.387 |       165 | Rwanda                         | RWA              | 0.000057616483205264607379 |  197
 2010 |     264.024 |        32 | Central African Republic       | CAF              | 0.000059350908447181931090 |  196
```

etc.

Now to the question. Is there a way to get a `rank` and `per_capita` for every year`and every country, if we leave the `WHERE cp.year = 2010` out from the query?

So the result would be something like:

```
 year |  emissions  | countryid |          country_name          | country_iso_code |         per_capita         | rank
------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------+------
 2010 |     212.686 |        14 | Burundi                        | BDI              | 0.000024260031732887110996 |  201
 2009 |     210.686 |        14 | Burundi                        | BDI              | 0.000024260031732887110996 |  200
 2010 |    2020.517 |        40 | Congo, Dem. Rep.               | COD              | 0.000031314550846568314439 |  200
 2011 |    2020.517 |        40 | Congo, Dem. Rep.               | COD              | 0.000031314550846568314439 |  201
```

etc.

So basically, query everything from the tables and get a ranking for each country. I've understood that `partition by` could be of help here, but I don't know where it would fit in the above query as replacing ORDER BY with it gives funny results.

This is for creating an API that shows every years every emission data for specific country, and where they ranked in per_capita for said year.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the `rank()` to:

```
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(emissions / NULLIF(population, 0), 0) DESC) as rank
```

If you want the *rank* for just one year, then you can do this:

```
(sum(case when cp.year = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) over
 (order by case when cp.year = 2010 then coalesce(emissions / nullif(population, 0) end) -
 sum(case when cp.year = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cp.year, coalesce(emissions / nullif(population, 0)) +
 1
)
```

The ranking is a bit tricky because you have to take duplicates with the same values into account.  Otherwise, you can just do:

```
select . . .,
       max(case when year = 2010 then rank_year end) over (partition by countryid) as rank_2010
from (select . . .,
             rank() over (order by coalesce(emissions / nullif(population, 0), 0) desc) as rank_year

      from . . .
     ) t
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I only have one emission value per year for each country, so there's no need to choose the max every year, etc. And the 2010 was just an example, I don't really need any specific year.

I'll see what I can do with your help, thanks.